# Is event emitter generic parameter type check by tsc in angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

Consider this code

```
@Component({
    selector : 'child',
    template : `
        <button (click)="sendNotification()">Notify my parent!</button>
    `
})
class Child {
    @Output() notifyParent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    sendNotification() {
        this.notifyParent.emit('Some value to send to the parent');
    }
}

@Component({
    selector : 'parent',
    template : `
        <child (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)"></child>
    `
})
class Parent {
    getNotification(evt: boolean) {
        // Do something with the notification (evt) sent by the child!
    }
}
```

Technically `getNotification(evt: boolean)` have the wrong parameter type, but tsc do not throw an error? I have also tried multiple event type pair combinations and it seems like none of them reach error as long as the type is in scope.

In fact anytime`$event` is passed in, it seems like ngcli tsc will ignore the type parameter.

For example

```
(ngModelChange)="selectTest($event)"

selectTest(test: anyType) {

}
```

The above will always compile.

Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I am using ng-cli ie. `ng serve`

Here is the version I am using

```
@angular/cli: 1.3.2
node: 8.2.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.6
@angular/common: 4.3.6
@angular/compiler: 4.3.6
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/forms: 4.3.6
@angular/http: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6
@angular/router: 4.3.6
@angular/cli: 1.3.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6
@angular/language-service: 4.3.6
```

Comment: Which version of cli are you using?

Comment: @mok I edited the post to include the version.

Comment: Typescript can not know that. The relationship between these methods are handled by Angular. The `(notifyParent)="getNotification($event)"` in the html for example, how can typescript know the type of `$event`? It can't. If you don't give a parameter for the specific method like `(notifyParent)="getNotification()"` but have a parameter in your component then angular-cli may sense something is wrong during aot build.

Comment: @echonax so what is the extent of typescript type check at compile time for angular4?

Comment: @Jal AFAIK you can't typecheck html/ts relations only ts/ts relations

Comment: @echonax I see, I remember seeing someone pointing out [this src](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/compiler/src/view_compiler) on some blog  and I mistakenly believed that angular4 typecheck all files regardless if its html or not.